# Understanding NAT concepts

Tags: linux, networking, ip, virtual-machine, nat

I began learning networking on Linux, and I am looking for a way to associate a particular IP to a particular MAC address (i.e. a way to edit the NAT table?). Actually I am trying to assign some IPs to my virtual machines, and want to forward packets through to these IPs.

Here is my specific use-case: I have virtual machines set up over a virtual network using KVM virtualization, and I'd like to send packets from and to virtual machines within this network.

Answer (score 1):

`NAT` (Network Address Translation) has nothing common with the goals you described. Correspondence between IP and MAC addresses is kept using mechanism named `ARP` (Address Resolution Protocol) for IP version 4 and Neighbour Discovery for IP version 6. In rare circumstances, you can maintain the neighbour list manually, but it's rarely needed.

For assigning IP to virtual machines, there are a few ways, depended on the concrete virtualization software you use. For example, for LXC containers, the simplest one is to create bridge, attach external network interface to this bridge and, when creating a container, attach its external link end to this bridge; the LXC layer itself will provide IP assignment restriction. For full virtualization software (like VirtualBox, VMWare), please read its documentation; usually this is either, yes, NAT (but in this case the guest won't be getting a dedicated IP address on the external side), bridging, or ever routing (in that case, you need to provide a IP subblock routing into your site network, either static or dynamic).

I guess this answer contains enough set of keywords to continue your searching. If no, you can reformulate your question and retry. But, https://serverfault.com/ looks for me as more appropriate place for such topics.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Netch, can you also make the question heading more appropriate.So that this post could be more useful.